# Website breaks on iPad tablets

Tags: html

Used crossbrowser testing and my website works on almost every single device. On an android tablet the same size as an iPad tablet...my site displays correctly on the android but not the ipad. Can using bad break points in media queries cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Add all of these media queries to your css and it will work

```css
/*
  Based on:
  1. http://stephen.io/mediaqueries
  2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
*/

/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* 
  iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries
  It's noteworthy that these media queries are also the same for iPod Touch generations 1-4.
*/

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {
  
}

/* iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* HTC One portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* HTC One portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* HTC One landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/*
  iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries
  If you're looking to target only 3rd and 4th generation Retina iPads 
  (or tablets with similar resolution) to add @2x graphics,
  or other features for the tablet's Retina display, use the following media queries.
*/

/* Retina iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/* Retina iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/* Retina iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/*
  iPad 1 & 2 Media Queries
  If you're looking to supply different graphics or choose different typography 
  for the lower resolution iPad display, the media queries below will work 
  like a charm in your responsive design!
*/

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad mini in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad mini in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad mini in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait and landscape */
@media
  (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 800px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 landscape */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    
}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    
}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Laptops non-retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    
}

/* Laptops retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    
}

/* Apple Watch */
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

}

/* Moto 360 Watch */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 218px)
  and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

}
```